# Spinner saves selected item well but when you reopen app says null

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have this class where I am using a spinner but I am yet to understand why my spinner is returning null. I have saved it well on my db but once you close the app and open it again it returns nulls, I want to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: can u share the db related code saving part and retrieving part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.currency_spinner);
```

try it ， good luck，not use

> getActivity().findViewById(R.id.currency_spinner);